# Search in sqlite database by criterias selected with checkbox

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

I have in my app a database with two tables : country and rights. Long story short, the db tells me whether a right (there is 10 rights in total) is legal or not in a specific country.

Now, I want the user to be able to search in my db by criterias. I have a layout with checkbox. If the user check a box, it mean he want to see every country in where the right is legal. For exemple, if he check the box "criteria1" and "criteria6", the user want the list of every country where criteria1 and criteria6 are legal, but we don't care wether the other rights are legal or not.

I asigned values to the checkboxs (1 if legal, 0 if illegal, just like in my db) and passes all of them to the activity who display the result of the search. 
My problem is, I can't figure out how to search in my database. I need to only get the country where where the selected criters are equal to 1, but I don't know how to formulate my sql request (since I never know which criterias are going to be checked or not). My request need to only be about the criterias who has the value 1.

I had the idea of sending all my values to a function (witch returns a cursor) where I excecute a select statement if the value is equal to one, but I don't know how I could join all the result of my selects in a cursor. I also thought about using "CASE WHEN..." but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a clue on how I could deal with my search ?

If you need precisions on my problem, please ask.

Comment: search here in the docs:https://sqlite.org/docs.html and Android Documention: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html and API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: `select ... from country inner join criterias where ((criteria=?) or (criteria=?)) and crit_value = 1 group by country_id having count(1) >= 2` .... where `((criteria=?) or ...)` part is generated by joining "criteria=?" with "or" selected criterias times and "having" part is also generated where "2" is a number of criteria selected ... also you have to pass new `String[] { selected_criteria_id1, selected_criteria_id2, selected_criteria_idN }` which is alos generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGRV2qY9ZiU&list=PL200JxfhYIgCrrpH4rCz-uNfBTb5sng1e) has the right idea.

The clip may be a bit slow but it does exactly what you want.

He creates a custom string based on if checkbox is checked and removes it from the string if unchecked.

To get what you want, you need to do a couple of things.

First, create a table with countries as rows, and rights as columns. Add 1 for right is present in country and 0 if not. Get this into an sqlite database (eg import via csv in DB browser for SQLite, free software; don't forget to create the android_metadata table in the sqlite database - search online for this). Import the database in the app (there is plenty of documentation for this online).

Second, change the text inputed in the if/else checkbox part of the script (he writes fruit names, you write for ex. "right1 = 1", or the exact query the checkbox should do on the column right1).

You also need to pay attention to the selection.add and selection.remove (know that selection is an array list which will store all your criteria for search by column).

Third, you need to change the content of his finalSelection (View view).

Delete all he has written and just create two strings:

String final1 = android.text.TextUtils.join(" or ", selection);

String final2 = "select country from table where " + final1;

The string final2 is your key for a cursor with a rawQuery. Just create a cursor in the database and pass the key to it. This can be done easily.

PS the method android.text.TextUtils.join() is amazing :)

You can place the operator of choice there.

If you need more than one operator (and, or etc), you can create different ArrayLists which you fill in the if/else checkbox is filled and join later in the finalSelection.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Good code requires also an if/else for the whole thing. So if no checkbox is checked, you need to have an output for that situation also. Like a popup which says no selection made.  Or you may just show the entire table. You will surely find documentation online for this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, btw, if you have too many checkboxes, you will get a warning in the XML file (layout has more than 80 views is bad for performance).

In order to get around that, you need to get to know grid views a bit better. After reading a few tutorials on the basic use of GridViews, a good start for checkboxes inside them is [here](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/).

It may seem like a lot, but you need to learn to use holders to get information out of the getView of the modified BaseAdapter.

If you want to understand it better, follow the arrPath.

It is a `String[]` filled with all the paths of images found inside the cursor (string values from the `dataColumnIndex`, which contains paths of images).

Within the `onClick()` listener of the Button, from the arrPath he extracts only the rows of the cursor that were selected by checkbox click (thumbnailsselection[i] is a boolean - with a value TRUE/FALSE for each row in the cursor).

The selected paths are placed in the `selectImages` String, separated by OR.